# How to run tests in dockerfile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, containers

I have a visual studio application and I want to run my tests in dockerfile once the container is created. I am using .net framework 4.7.2
Here's is a little sample of my code,

```
 public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}


using NUnit.Framework;

namespace aspnetapptest
{
    using System;

    [TestFixture]
    public class aspnetapptest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod_Success()
        {
            //Arrange
            var teststring = "this is a test";

            //Act
            var resversestring = Reverse(teststring);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(resversestring, "tset a si siht");
        }

        public void TestMethod_Failure()
        {
            //Arrange
            var teststring = "this is a test";

            //Act
            var resversestring = Reverse(teststring);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(resversestring, "this is a test");
        }
    }
}
```

And the dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 as build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# build runtime image
FROM build AS test
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet test aspnetapptest -c Release
RUN dotnet new nunit
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet test --logger:trx
ENTRYPOINT ["aspnetapp.dll"]
```

The above dockerfile is not producing any test results, could you please assist

Comment: What does it produce? What commands are you running and what is their output?

Comment: I am running docker-compose up which produces the image and container but doesn't run the tests on the container. Also, I can't see the .trx file

Comment: Is this commands running tests on your local sys - `RUN dotnet test aspnetapptest -c Release`?

Comment: this is the command 'RUN dotnet test --logger:trx' that I am trying to run the test